# Problema em imagem SVG. Evento mouseenter(), mousemove() e mouseleave()

Tags: jquery, svg, eventos-do-mouse

Tenho uma imagem SVG com os Estados do País e preciso que, ao passar o mouse sobre um Estado, a imagem com o nome do Estado apareça e siga o mouse.

Já fiz a imagem aparecer e desaparecer com os eventos `mouseenter` e `mouseleave`, porém, não consigo fazer ela seguir o mouse dentro do Estado com `mousemove`.

**Segue o código:**

```
$('path.str0').mouseenter(function(){
            var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
            var pieces = thisClass.split(' ');

            //Estou mexendo aqui. Ewerton Melo
            $('img').filter( '.' + pieces[2]).css("display", "block");
            //Até aqui

            $(this).attr('fill', "#00d4ff");
        }).mousemove(function(e){
            var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coodrinates
            var mousey = e.pageY + 20; //Get Y coordinates
            var tipWidth = $(this).width(); //Find width of tooltip
            var tipHeight = $(this).height(); //Find height of tooltip

            //Distance of element from the right edge of viewport
            var tipVisX = $(window).width() - (mousex + tipWidth);
            //Distance of element from the bottom of viewport
            var tipVisY = $(window).height() - (mousey + tipHeight);

            if ( tipVisX < 20 ) { //If tooltip exceeds the X coordinate of viewport
                mousex = e.pageX - tipWidth - 20;
            } if ( tipVisY < 20 ) { //If tooltip exceeds the Y coordinate of viewport
                mousey = e.pageY - tipHeight - 20;
            }
            //Absolute position the tooltip according to mouse position
            $(this).css({  top: mousey, left: mousex });
        }).mouseleave(function(){
            var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
            var pieces = thisClass.split(' ');
            //console.log($('img').filter( '.' + pieces[2]).css("display", "none"));
            $('img').filter( '.' + pieces[2]).css("display", "none");
            $(this).attr('fill', "#00b2d6");
        });
```

Comment: O código JavaScript não é suficiente. Inclua também o código SVG e o HTML da página (`img`).

Answer (score 1):

Como você não incluiu o CSS ou o HTML, vou assumir que o SVG é uma imagem qualquer, e que você não tem um CSS pré-definido.

Pelo seu JavaScript, você também tem uma imagem `img`.

```
$('img').filter( ... );
```

Eu criei um SVG simples (um círculo) que representa o SVG que você está usando:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200">
    <circle class="a b c" r="100" cx="100" cy="100" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

e troquei a referência `path.str0` do seu código por ele para este exemplo:

```
$('circle').mouseenter(function(){
   var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
   var pieces = thisClass.split(' ');
```

Também criei uma imagem, um `<img>` e pus três classes arbitrárias `a`, `b` e `c` no SVG, já que seu código tenta extrair a terceira classe do `svg` para referenciar a `img`:

```
$('img').filter( '.' + pieces[2]).css("display", "block");
```

Aparentemente está tudo funcionando corretamente (o SVG muda de cor no `mouseover` e `mouseout`, a imagem desaparece, e as coordenadas mudam durante o `mousemove`. Eu inclui um DIV para monitorar a mudança de coordenadas do `mousemove`:

```
$('#coords').html('y: '+mousey+', x: '+mousex);
```

A mudança de coordenadas está acontecendo, mas não foi definido o tipo de posicionamento (estou assumindo que você não definiu isto no CSS). Portanto, não é um erro de SVG, mas de **CSS**. Para posicionar em CSS você precisa definir `position` além das coordenadas (`top`,`left`,`bottom` ou `right`). Vai funcionar se você acrescentar um CSS com:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Veja aqui neste **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/47A52/)** uma tentativa de reproduzir o seu problema e solução. Acho que você conseguirá adaptá-lo para o seu problema.

Comment: helderdarocha, muito obrigado, sua ajuda foi providencial para solução do meu problema.